# Forcing required format in Twig generated URL

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm forcing `XML` format for a certain action.

```php
/**
 * @Route(
 *      "/index.{_format}",
 *      name         = "index",
 *      requirements = {"_format" = "xml"},
 *      defaults     = {"_format" = "xml"}
 * )
 *
 * @Template
 */
public function index()
{
    // ...
}
```

Then on some Twig template I'm generating an absolute URL for this action.

```
{{ url('index') }}
```

The result is:

```
http://www.domain.com/index
```

But I expected:

```
http://www.domain.com/index.xml
```

How can I achieve the expected behaviour?

Comment: Maybe you have one else router with name `index`, that overridde it?

Comment: No, the route is unique (actually I'm using `index` as a placeholder for this question). Do you mean that it should work as I expected by default?

Comment: I was lying! Edited the question because I'm using `defaults`, I think that's the key of the problem...

Comment: And now it not work too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use:

```
{{ url('index', {"_format" = "xml"}) }}
```

And remove the `defaults = {"_format" = "xml"}` annotation.

Comment: It's `defaults` what causes the missing format. The solution is to remove that clause and using your code `{{ url('index', {"_format" = "xml"}) }}`. Can you review your answer?